# Maintain Feature Data without Creating It

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, update, feature-class

I work in City Gov. We utilize County Assessor data (Parcels) as they are updated from the Assessors office. Currently we store then in our Enterprise SDE system. As we get new updates, we have to shut down all users of Parcel data in order to delete the old set and overwrite with the new update.

Is there a way to update this data without having to shut down users? Some kind of versioning concept for maintainers vs. creators of gis data?

We are currently looking into TRUNCATE AND APPEND as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate and append should work. You may need to delete [shared locks](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27034) beforehand for the truncate to succeed.

A more complicated but potentially time-saving option is, if your parcel data includes a unique ID and a "date last modified" field, you could determine which records to update, insert or delete so that a smaller number of records will be affected.

I would just try the former and see how that works for you first as the latter can be difficult to implement and requires more rigorous data maintenance practices on the part of the data provider.

Comment: The problem with using the unique ID is that they don't utilize one. There is a parcel ID that is unique to each parcel, but in the case of a parcel split or merge, there is no rhyme or reason to what the new parcel(s) number will be. They may re-use the old one, create a completely new one, or use an old, already deleted one. It's crazy-making.