# Appending and Replacing some (but not all) Fields using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, parcel

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2.

My question is similar to [Maintain Feature Data without Creating It](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83152).

I am looking for a way to update our proprietary parcel layer with a shapefile downloaded from our county source. A truncate and append would work, but there are some fields that are not maintained by the county that are parcel specific (e.g., variances).

Is there a way to replace the updated fields while retaining selected existing fields, or do I need to maintain variances as a separate feature class that I spatial join to the append and truncated parcel layer?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question. Are you replacing/deleting all your rows and inserting the new data into your schema? You can use arcpy.da cursors to do this.